# Any links to microsoft topic explaining how manual mapping dll's works?

Tags: c++, portable-executable

i searched a lot but couldn't find where is the original thread that started to teach others how to manual map a dll image into another target process address space can someone link it?

Because i don't think people just started this without knowing how it works.

Comment: Are you trying to inject a DLL into some process?

Comment: @armagedescu yeah just for educational purposes am trying to learn more about windows internals and how they actually work in general. but i couldn't find any ms article talking about mapping a dll into another process.

Comment: What exactly you do you mean Mapping into Another Process? You make another process to load any dll? Making some process to load a dll is named dll injection. I described in an article step by step how to do inject https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34237/A-C-Style-of-Intercepting-Functions see at the end of article

Comment: @armagedescu i think you misunderstood me but i don't want to use LoadLibrary to load or inject my dll i want to map it into the other process

Comment: Please describe exactly that you mean, step by step. How exactly I misunderstood you and what you want to do differently? What exactly is the result what should be another one and different than injecting?

Comment: @armagedescu i want to inject my dll into a process using manual mapping but i couldn't find an article describing how does it work like from scratch.

Comment: There is no way to avoid using system APIs, even if you do manual loading. Lots of system API function you will call, but only LoadLibrary you try to avoid. Ok, suppose it makes sense. But why wouldn't you try first with LoadLibrary? Try to succeed with some method before trying any method that is more laborious.

Comment: @armagedescu because am trying to learn the hard way i already know how loadlibrary works i want to do other internal stuff by my own.

Comment: Maybe you know how the loadlibrary works. But you also need to know how to call it inside a foreign process. Because to load the library manyally with without calling LoadLibrary, you will call many other system functions, that will be the same. You have no way to write a foreign process without calling sistem functions. The technique is identically exactly the same, with or without calling LoadLibrary.

Comment: You first must understand the whole process of breaking the process boundaries. It is not about LoadLibrary at all. It is about writing the foreign process memory, requiring process rights to do it, calling functions inside the foreign process. That is first thing you have to learn.

Comment: @armagedescu is that the pe format all about?

Comment: Ok, what is exactly the problem? Have you written any code and experience any problems? Can you post any pieces of code that can reproduce any of your problems? Is there any problem that we can discuss about? You ask for help without providing even a single line of your code to discuss. So, take the link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format read documentation, show what you have done if you experience any problems

Comment: @armagedescu actually this is the solution i just wanted to understand that if i needed to code or understand how could i map my dll i would need to understand the pe format to do that thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, Windows is a closed source OS so its internals are either undocumented or unofficial.

Here's the link to a youtube tutorial how to do it "manually"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzZTXcBu3cE

Steps in general copied from the video:

1. Load your raw DLL data
2. Map sections into target process
3. Inject loader shellcode
4. Apply relocation
5. Fix imports
6. Execute TLS callbacks
7. Call DllMain
8. Clean up